# Synchronize windows and docker on wsl2 is too slow

Tags: docker, ruby-on-rails-4, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## environment

windows10 home

wsl

```
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Running         2
```

docker

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.10
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        9424aeaee9
 Built:             Thu May 28 22:16:49 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

rails4 runs on docker and use docker-sync

```
sudo docker-sync-stack start
```

## problem

When I change code on windows10(webstorm), after 2-3min(sometimes more) synchronize with docker on wsl2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I didi git clone on /c/mnt/{somewhere} directory, docker-sync takes time a lot.
But after I did git clone on root directory in wsl, it takes only 1sec.